# Inserting an element after another element's child

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

For example: I want to add div inside id123 after sth2 using jquery. I think i knew how to do that after every sth2 but not after 1 certain.

```
<div class="id123">
 <div class="a"></div>
 ..
 <div class="sth1"></div>
 <div class="sth2"></div>
 "some text"
 <div class="end"></div>
</div>
<div class="id124">
 <div class="a"></div>
 ..
 <div class="sth1"></div>
 <div class="sth2"></div>
 "some text"
 <div class="end"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.after()` method:

```
$('#id123 .sth2').after('<div></div>');
```

Comment: @Luffy No, that won't work, that would work using `.insertAfter()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `after` method to insert the div after every .sth2

```
$('.sth2').after('<div />');
```

If you want to insert it after a specific one, it looks like this:

```
$('.sth2').first().after('<div />');
```

or

```
$('.sth2').last().after('<div />');
```

or even

```
$('.sth2:eq(1)').after('<div />');
```

to select an element with a specific index.